# Coalesce with baby_squeel / arel in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel, coalesce, squeel

I am trying to write a rather complicated query using [baby_squeel](https://github.com/rzane/baby_squeel). The query requires the use of the `coalesce` SQL function. `coalesce` is used as an example a couple of times on the baby_squeel home page but when I try to use it in a query I get a no method error.

Example below:

```
result = Table.selecting { |t| [t.col1, 
                                ((coalesce(t.col2, 0) + coalesce(t.col3, 0)).sum.as('column'))] }
              .where.has { |t| t.col4 == 'some condition' }
              .grouping { |t| t.col1 }
```

I am using Rails 5 and baby_squeel 1.2. The query is called inside of a private controller function.

Why is this happening? Do I need to `require` something or define the function myself using arel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will help anyone, but I found what I was missing. Since I gave arity to the block I had to reference the functions I wanted to use with the airty variable in this case `t`. The correct code is:

```
result = Table.selecting { |t| [t.col1, 
                                ((t.coalesce(t.col2, 0) + t.coalesce(t.col3, 0)).sum.as('column'))] }
              .where.has { |t| t.col4 == 'some condition' }
              .grouping { |t| t.col1 }
```